# --skip-sprockets and --skip-javascript still generates app/assets/javascripts/application.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I plan to use bowerjs to manage front-end dependencies and gulp.js to concatenate and minify and compile the front-end code. Consequently, I want to skip the Rails assets pipeline, including sprockets. I run the following command to skip the assets pipeline:

```
$ rails new myapp --skip-sprockets --skip-javascripts --database=postgresql -T
```

However, I notice the following:

```
 create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
 create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
 create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
 create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

And when I look at the application.js file, I notice the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

It did comment our sprockets in config/application.rb:

```
# require "sprockets/railtie"
```

And the Gemfile does not contain

```
sass-rails
uglifier
coffee-rails
jquery-rails
turbolinks
```

But why did it generate files in app/assets?

Comment: My guess, Rails 5 comes with Actioncable and it relies on Javascript which in turn has to be generated to work.

Comment: I just tried this with -C flag to exclude Action Cable and it still generates the files listed

Answer (score 5):

Check you syntax. Correct is a
`--skip-javascript`